# Xcode "failed to get the task for process -1"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode13

Since a few weeks I can't launch app on iOS from Xcode because of that error, and logs in details is:

```
Details

Could not launch “Wui”
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: failed to get the task for process -1
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 855031;
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = DBGLLDBLauncher;
    RawUnderlyingErrorMessage = "failed to get the task for process -1";
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_isWireless" = 1;
    "device_model" = "iPhone11,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.0 (19A346)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 11207;
    "operation_errorCode" = 3;
    "operation_errorDomain" = IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = DBGLLDBLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.5";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.6 (Build 20G165)
Xcode 13.0 (19234) (Build 13A233)
Timestamp: 2021-10-02T15:12:55+02:00
```

I have tried with and without a cable to transfer the app.
It's the same error for React Native and SwiftUI app, different building profile, reinstall xcode, clean build, reinstall pods, ...

I also tried to Edit scheme and unchecked "Debug executable", and this time the app reboot few times and Xcode say: "Unable to launch com.myApp.blabla"

If someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Manage Certificate > + > Apple Development
2. Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Download Manual Profiles

I have got a same error.
It was solved by the above operation.

My background
-The last build was successful a month ago.
-I didn't changed my device.
-I haven't registered as Apple Developer Program.